# gps location in web page

Tags: java, javascript, android, gps, coordinates

Can I get gps coordinates from smartphone with android by java script request?
Can it be done from web browser or do I need to create app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a web application using `navigator.geolocation`.

The Android browser will still prompt the user and they can deny the request.

Comment: can navigator.location be used to access gps device coordinated or just location over ip ?

Comment: It does. If gps is enabled it will use gps, otherwise it will fall back to network.

Comment: is there any way to know if coordinates are from gps device or ip by location?

Comment: No, but the accuracy (http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy) parameter in the Position response can give you a good idea. Also when you request with getCurrentPosition() you can use the PositionOptions (http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position-options) parameter to specify whether you want high accuracy (gps) or not.